# Get Taggables by common tags using rtconner/laravel-tagging

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, tags

I'm quite new to Laravel. I installed RConner's Laravel-Tagging plugin. It works fine.

On a post page, I would like to get other posts (taggables) having similar tags.
I know I can do it using sql joins and count (but not really how)

I tried to add a scope-method to TaggableTrait, but I'm struggling with the joins.
I'd like to know if there is a "Laravel's Way" of doing the magic.

Thank you !

Edit : 
Actually, what I'm trying to achieve, is retrieving "taggables", ordered by number of common tags with the current content.

I'm trying to add a scope-method to TaggableTrait such as :

```
public function scopeWithCommonTag($query, $tagNames)
{
    $tagNames = TaggingUtil::makeTagArray($tagNames);

    $normalizer = \Config::get('tagging::normalizer');
    $normalizer = empty($normalizer) ? '\Conner\Tagging\TaggingUtil::slug' : $normalizer;

    $tagNames = array_map($normalizer, $tagNames);

    $query = $query->whereHas('tagged', function ($q) use ($tagNames) {
        $q->whereIn('tag_slug', $tagNames)->groupBy('taggable_id')->orderByRaw('count(*)');
    });
}
```

The resulting query is :

```
select * from `contents` where (
    select count(*) from `tagging_tagged` 
    where `tagging_tagged`.`taggable_id` = `contents`.`id` 
    and `tagging_tagged`.`taggable_type` = ? 
    and `tag_slug` in (?, ?) 
    group by `taggable_id` 
    order by count(*)
) >= 1
```

What I need is :

```
select * from `contents` where taggable_id in (
    select taggable_id,count(*) as common_tags 
    from `tagging_tagged` 
    where `tagging_tagged`.`taggable_id` = `contents`.`id` 
    and `tagging_tagged`.`taggable_type` = ? 
    and `tag_slug` in (?, ?) 
    group by `taggable_id` 
    order by common_tags desc
) limit 3;
```

Maybe something like this (I tried to use whereIn('id',closure) but obviously, it doesn't join the "tagged" table...

```
$query = $query->whereHas('tagged', function ($q) use ($tagNames) {
    $q->select(array('taggable_id',\DB::raw('count(*) as common_tags')))->whereIn('tag_slug', $tagNames)->groupBy('taggable_id')->orderByRaw('common_tags desc');
});
```

It's a bit over my head. Any leads ?

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it using Eloquent if your relations are correct.

I don't know what is your Schema so this solution is in a generalized form.

1 - Get the ids of all the tags of a post.

2- Then you can query your relation using eloquent whereHas method. Something like this

```
$postTags = [1,2,3,4,5]; //  List of tags id of a particular post

$similarPosts = Post::whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($postTags) {
    $q->whereIn('id', $postTags);
})->get();
```

Read this [Querying Relations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations)

**Update**:

I just looked at the package it has a predefined method to get similar articles which is also doing the same thing as mentioned above.

Read the [docs](https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-tagging) of the package

```
Article::withAnyTag(array('Gardening','Cooking'))->get();
```

Comment: I edited my question to be more specific about my needs, but you got me one step further. Thank you for your reply and the link to the doc.